# Turn base64 string into png for upload to s3 in frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I feel like I'm going crazy, I really hope this is not a duplication although I did find multiple similar issues but none of the solutions worked for me.
I'm using react-signature-canvas to let people sign on the website. That library offers a `toDataURL()` method, which turns the canvas into a base64 string. I then remove the `"data:image/png;base64,"` from that string and turn it into a Blop using the fetch function. Getting a presigned URL I use `axios.put()` to send the image to an S3 bucket. However when I download that image from that bucket I can't open it because it's corrupted. When I put the dataURL into a base64 to image converter online the string works.

Here is my code so far:

```
const fileUpload = async signatureImageSrc => {
  const signatureImage = await (await fetch(signatureImageSrc)).blob();
  const fileBody = new FormData();
  fileBody.append("signature", signatureImage);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  const fileName = id + "-" + "signature.png";
  axios
    .post("/upload_url", {fileName: fileName, fileType: "image/png"}, config)
    .then(res => {
      axios.put(res.data, fileBody, config).then(res => console.log(res));
    });
};
```

I have tried changing the type of the blop (because it currently set to `text/html`) as well as sending it appended to a Form data object, as well as changing the `Content-Type` in the config object. I tried creating it as a file ( `new File([blop], fileName)`) and sending it through and more.
It always gets corrupted or sometimes it's a `.json` or `.html` file.

Comment: Try adding another key-value along with headers key```responseType: "arraybuffer"``` to the axios config object.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that but unfortunately nothing changed, the file that gets uploaded is also corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work.

I used a function to create a blob from the base64 string and then turned that blob into a file by adding the lastModifiedDate and name property to it.
Additionally I did not use a form data element anymore but instead uploaded that created file directly to the S3 bucket.

The code looks like this now:

```
  const fileUpload = signatureImageSrc => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    const configBlop = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };

    const blob = b64toBlob(signatureImageSrc, "image/png");
    const fileName = id + "-" + "beauftragung-unterschrift.png";
    const file = blobToFile(blob, fileName);
    axios
      .post("/upload_url", {fileName: fileName, fileType: "image/png"}, config)
      .then(res => {
        axios.put(res.data, file, configBlop).then(res => console.log(res));
      });
  };
```

The function to create the Blob is taken [from here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/322/how-to-convert-a-base64-image-into-a-image-file-and-upload-it-with-an-asynchronous-form-using-jquery) and the blobToFile function looks like this:

```
  const blobToFile = (theBlob, fileName) => {
    theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    theBlob.name = fileName;
    return theBlob;
  };
```